# Creating dynamically-named data tables in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

Suppose I want to dynamically create data tables in a loop, for example:

```
for(i in 1:3){

  paste0('a',i)= data.table(x=1)


}
```

This returns an error.  What is the syntax to do this properly?

Comment: Do you want to store these `data.table`s in a list? Try `n <- 3; setNames(replicate(n, data.table(x = 1), simplify = FALSE), nm = paste0("a", 1:n))`

Comment: Well, the "correct" way is not to do this at all. Generally it's much better to work with variables in a list rather than creating a bunch of related variables with indexes embedded in their name.